# Create index on a converted sub document field with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

Using Spring Data for Mongo (any recent version) I'm trying to set an index on a field that is persisted as a sub-document through the help of a `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter` (it is actually two fields)

My document class looks like this:

```
@Document
class Doc {
  @Indexed
  private MySuperField superField;

  // id, getter setter ignored
}
```

While my document structure in database looks like this:

```
{
  "superField": {
     "field1": 123,
     "field2": 456
  }
}
```

The index gets created on `superField` - while I would like it to be on `superField.field1`. of course from Spring's point of view it is logical - only the `Converter` has any notion of the sub document.

Is there any way to position the index on the right field while still using annotations? Otherwise I'll have to use a mongo template to explicitely create it...

Note : the actual use case behind this is to store a ZonedDateTime without loosing the original timezone information. First field is epoch, second is original timezone.

**EDIT** : I need to set expiration time of the index. Which makes compound indices irrelevant sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think compound indexes are the way to go here, try this:

```
@Document
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(name = "superfield_field1", def = "{ 'superField.field1': 1 }")
})
class Doc {
  @Indexed
  private MySuperField superField;

  // id, getter setter ignored
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten one requirement in the question (and edited it). Compound indices do not allow to set expiration time. But thanks for answering.

Comment: ohh okay, then I believe mongo template is the only way